# How can I configure database proxy on lambda in serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless` framework to provision infrastructure on AWS. And I need to add `database proxy` on my lambda but I couldn't find how to configure that. I have read the doc https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/ but it doesn't mention anything relate to database proxy.

Below screenshot is the bottom of lambda in aws console. How can I add the proxy via `serverless.yml`?

[image]

Comment: Probably need to custom define it using [Resources](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/) section.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your RDS server and click on the proxy
2. Copy the Proxy ARN
3. Edit your serverless.yml and

```
provider:
  name: aws
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "rds-db:connect"
          Resource: "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:123123123:admin:blah-123abc123abc/*"
```

Note that "rds" in the ARN was changed to "rds-db" and "db-proxy" in the ARN was changed to "admin" (the admin user of the database). `sls deploy` and check the lambda. You should see the proxy in the database proxy configuration section.

For example, the Proxy ARN I copied from RDS was

`arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123123123:db-proxy:blah-123abc123abc`

and I edited it to be

`arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:123123123:admin:blah-123abc123abc/*`

Also, be sure your lambda is in the [same Vpc](https://forum.serverless.com/t/lambda-deploy-into-vpc/5829) as the RDS proxy or it will not be able to connect.

I am using:

```
% sls --version
Framework Core: 2.50.0
Plugin: 5.4.3
SDK: 4.2.3
Components: 3.13.2
```

Comment: In my case I needed to change `dbuser` in resource string to `admin` like
`arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:123123123:dbuser:blah-123abc123abc/*` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html)